# AWS ELB with Apache 404 message show Port 80 even though I'm accessing through https

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

I'm using ELB with two AWS instances.

My ELB setup is like

80 -> 80

443 -> 80

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at www.hello.com Port 80
```

Now, if I access the page at https://www.hello.com and I can see the 404 error message which says that server is running on Port 80.

Is there a way to change that to 443?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't change it to 443 because apache is upstream and does not know whether the initial request came via 80 or 443 to the ELB. However you could change the `ErrorDocument` to a different template that does not mention the port number.

Comment: @SteveE. Awesome Thank you.